# Nested breakable boxes with line on the left (any package)

Tags: page-breaking, boxes

I'm trying to create an environment like `quotation`, but with a line on the left.
I would also like it to support multiple paragraphs, footnotes, math environments and floats (basically you should be able to wrap it around any, or most content and it should just work).

The difficult thing is that I want it to handle **pagebreaks**, even when nested.
From the TeXFAQ entry about [breaking boxes of text](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-breakbox), I know it is possible to do this with the [boites](https://ctan.org/pkg/boites) package, but it breaks floats and footnotes, sadly, so this is not an option for me. There have been [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/various-defined-breakable-boxes-inside-breakable-box-using-overlapping) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417271/breakable-box-in-breakable-box-with-tcolorbox?noredirect=1&lq=1) before, but for whole boxes instead of only left lines. I'm not sure if this question might be easier to answer. I am also aware that this is apparently not possible to solve using the `framed`, `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` packages (see the package documentations).

There is a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424576/control-page-breaks-in-multiple-frames-via-mdframed) about `mdframed` specifically, instead of about the problem in general, but the boxes in the answer do not work with arbitrary content. ([previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624892/nested-breakable-boxes-with-line-on-the-left) was marked as duplicate, this is to clarify why I think it isn't)

Can this be done?

Example:
[image: Example]

Example code adapted from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018493/vertical-line-with-every-quotation):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newenvironment{quotationb}%
{\begin{leftbar}}%
{\end{leftbar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{quotationb}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{quotationb}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\begin{quotationb}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{quotationb}
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{quotationb}
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{quotationb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible approach: Two pass, first pass saves start and end position and pages of each environment, on second pass draw the lines based on these saved positions using the background picture of the shipout hooks. All the environment controls of the typeout is the increase of the left margin.

Comment: Your example image has no top or bottom margin; where would you want the footnote text to go? Will no pages have these margins? I don't quite understand what good wrapping floats in this sort of environment would be. I imagine you want the floats to appear in the indented level they were defined in which seems to defeat the whole point of floating.

Comment: @Dan for these cases, the environment should behave like the `quotation` environment. So footnotes should go at the bottom of the page as usual and floats should be placed depending on the placement specifier h/t/c etc.
The margins of pages shouldn't matter much for the behaviour and should be user definable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a sufficient option. It uses [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to draw the vertical rules, allows for nesting and adjustment of the indentation and rule width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage,eso-pic}
\usepackage[savepos,abspage,user]{zref}

\newcounter{newleftbar}
\newlength{\leftbarindent}
\newlength{\leftbarwidth}
\setlength{\leftbarwidth}{2pt}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{leftbar}{ O{2em} }{%
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \def\@leftbarindent{#1}%
  \addtolength{\leftbarindent}{\@leftbarindent}%
  \edef\leftbarnest{\thenewleftbar}%
  \stepcounter{newleftbar}% New leftbar environment
  \edef\theleftbar{\thenewleftbar}%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{#1}{0pt}
    \leavevmode% Start paragraph
    \zsavepos{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top}% Save position of left bar top
    \zlabel{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top-page}% Save page of left bar top
    % Store left bar top's text block top/bottom
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
      \noexpand\AtTextUpperLeft{\noexpand\zsavepos{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ftt}}%
      \noexpand\AtTextLowerLeft{\noexpand\zsavepos{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ftb}}%
    }%
    \noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
      \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top-page}{abspage}{0}=\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom-page}{abspage}{0}
        % Single page left bar
        \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top-page}{abspage}{0}=\noexpand\arabic{abspage}
          \noexpand\put(\dimexpr\zposx{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top}sp-#1,\dimexpr\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom}sp-.2\baselineskip){%
            \noexpand\rule{\leftbarwidth}{\dimexpr\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top}sp-\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom}sp+\baselineskip}}%
        \noexpand\fi
      \noexpand\fi
      \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top-page}{abspage}{0}<\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom-page}{abspage}{0}
        % Multipage left bar
        \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top-page}{abspage}{0}=\noexpand\arabic{abspage}
          % First page bar
          \noexpand\put(\dimexpr\zposx{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top}sp-#1,\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ftb}sp){%
            \noexpand\rule{\leftbarwidth}{\dimexpr\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top}sp-\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ftb}sp+.8\baselineskip}}%
        \noexpand\fi
        \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\arabic{abspage}>\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top-page}{abspage}{0}
          \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\arabic{abspage}<\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom-page}{abspage}{0}
            % Middle page bar
            \noexpand\put(\dimexpr\zposx{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top}sp-#1,\dimexpr\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ftb}sp-.2\baselineskip){%
              \noexpand\rule{\leftbarwidth}{\dimexpr\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ftt}sp-\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ftb}sp}}%
          \noexpand\fi
        \noexpand\fi
        \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\zref@extractdefault{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom-page}{abspage}{0}=\noexpand\arabic{abspage}
          % Last page bar
          \noexpand\put(\dimexpr\zposx{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-top}sp-#1,\dimexpr\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom}sp-.2\baselineskip){%
            \noexpand\rule{\leftbarwidth}{\dimexpr\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ltt}sp-\zposy{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom}sp+.2\baselineskip}}%
        \noexpand\fi
      \noexpand\fi
    }}\x
    \ignorespaces
}{%
    \zlabel{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom-page}% Save page of let bar bottom
    \zsavepos{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-bottom}% Save position of left bar bottom
    % Store left bar bottom's text block top/bottom
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
      \noexpand\AtTextUpperLeft{\noexpand\zsavepos{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ltt}}%
      \noexpand\AtTextLowerLeft{\noexpand\zsavepos{leftbar-\leftbarnest-\theleftbar-ltb}}%
    }}\x%
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \addtolength{\leftbarindent}{-\@leftbarindent}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{leftbar}
  \lipsum[2]
  
  \begin{leftbar}[1em]
    \lipsum[3-12]
  \end{leftbar}
  
  \lipsum[13]
\end{leftbar}

\lipsum[14]

\begin{leftbar}[5pt]
  \lipsum[15]
\end{leftbar}

\lipsum[16]

\begin{leftbar}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \begin{leftbar}
    \lipsum[17]
  \end{leftbar}
\end{leftbar}

\lipsum[18]

\begin{leftbar}
  \lipsum[19]
  \begin{leftbar}
    \lipsum[20]
  \end{leftbar}
\end{leftbar}

\lipsum[21]

\begin{leftbar}
  \lipsum[22]
  \begin{leftbar}
    \lipsum[23]
    \begin{leftbar}
      \lipsum[24]
      \begin{leftbar}
        \lipsum[25]
      \end{leftbar}
      \lipsum[26]
    \end{leftbar}
    \lipsum[27]
  \end{leftbar}
  \lipsum[28]
\end{leftbar}

\lipsum[29]

\end{document}
```

[`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref) is used to capture the position of the start and end of the `leftbar` text block and absolute page number to identify whether the `leftbar` is on a single page or has to span multiple pages. In the latter case, the bar is split into a "first page bar", "middle page bar" (possibly non-existent) and a "last page bar".

This should work sufficiently for a `oneside` document, or `twoside` with similar margins. If the text blocks are offset (like in `twoside` mode), there may be placement issues, or the code has to be updated to accommodate for that.

Not much is done to check for nesting without content at some level, so manual vertical adjustment is required. Also, multiply consecutive closures (`\end{leftbar} \end{leftbar}`) may have some misalignment due to spacing from `adjustwidth`.

Comment: Wow...Very nice and interesting...

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer. I was able to get it to work with `twoside` mode (will post modified code later) by making the line placement relative to the current page's `\AtTextUpperLeft` position. The other limitations you mention are no big deal to me. However, I noticed a major bug with floats and footnotes: if you add
`A footnote\footnote{This collides with the leftbars}.
\begin{figure}[b!]
\textcolor{lightgray}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\caption{This also does}
\end{figure}`
directly after `\begin{document}`, the [leftbars extend too far downwards](https://i.imgur.com/prBHpPQ.png).

Comment: @Werner I also think it still works if you remove `\leftbarnest` everywhere, right?

Comment: @Matthias: Of course, there's no consideration made for floats or footnotes that are set within the text block, so the lines will overrun those.

Comment: @Werner Do you know how one would do this to prevent overrunning?

Comment: @Werner: I managed do it for footnotes by saving the position of the foottnoterule and adjusting the bar height. But for floats i have no idea how to do this in a sane way.

Comment: @Matthias: I haven't invested more time into this as I've been busy with other things. This might be a good start though for float detection and adjustment: [Is there a way to determine if there is a float on a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56673/5764)